# "ERROR: device UUID="xxx" not found" on boot after switchg to linux-lts kernel on Arch Linux

Tags: arch-linux, kernel, linux-kernel, grub2

```
ERROR: device UUID="xxx" not found. Skipping fsck.
mount: /new_chroot: can't find UUID="xxx".
```

This issue happened after I tried to switch from linux to linux-lts kernel.
I did

```
pacman -S linux-lts
pacman -S linus-lts-headers
pacman -Rc linux
```

I forgot to update the grub config.
From the live USB I mounted the root, did arch-chroot into it and did

```
grub-mkconfig -o /boot/grub/grub.cfg
mkinitcpio -p linux-lts
```

Both successful. Grub found the linux-lts image. But I still have the same error when I try to boot.

`blkid` and `cat /etc/fstab` show this same UUID.

Answer (score 0):

In my `/etc/default/grub` I had a line:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="loglevel=3 quiet pci=noacpi"
```

I changed it to:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="loglevel=3"
```

And updated the config:

```
grub-mkconfig -o /boot/grub/grub.cfg
```

After that, everything started to work. I don't know why it was working before and why it stopped.